# how to keep font size equal in all zoom levels?

Tags: css, zooming, font-size

I made some bubbles using icon fonts and text shadow, I need to keep the size of these bubbles equal in all zoom levels

here is my syntax

```
span.bubble_1 {
        position: absolute;
        top: percentage(22 / 661);
        left: percentage(66 / 658);

        &:before {
            content : attr(data-icon);
            color: transparent;
            opacity: 0.18;
            font-size: 132px;
            @include text-shadow(0 0 30px #0070b1);
        }
}
```

the font size actually is my bubble size,
I want my font size be equal in all zoom levels of browser

Is there any pure css way ?

**Edit :** I've searched alot and found out there is a CSS3 property called TEXT-SIZE-ADJUST but it's not supported in any major browsers

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

132 * zoomLevel

Be sure your zoom level value in one decimal.

Comment: are you want to make font size be dynamic? if so that's math logic to change the font size.. which 132 is current font size

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use javascript, here's the code:

HTML:

```
<p>This text will preserve its size</p>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = setSize();
window.onresize = setSize();

function setSize()
{
    para = document.querySelector('p');
    windowHeight = parseInt(window.innerHeight);
    newSize = 0.05*windowHeight;        // Change 0.05 to control size
    para.style.fontSize = newSize;  
}
```

In this simple code, the text will change position due to margin size change so just add the following to avoid that:

```
body {  margin: 0; }
```

This won't work on jsfiddle as the output area is not the web page itself. Run it directly.